# Change hover color on Table Rows in Ant-Design Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to set the background color on rows when the mouse is hovering them, I tried a few approaches, one with styled components, styling the table itself:

```
const StyledTable = styled((props) => <Table {...props} />)`
  & tbody > tr:hover {
    background: rgba(224, 248, 232, 1);
  }
`;
```

This almost works, when I hover over a row, first I see the color that I have set, and immediatelly after that it changes back to the default, so its transitioning between my light green and the default antd color. I can't even find their color when I inspect the rows in the stylings.

The second way that I tried is with normal css and a class name:

Where the css for the class is:

```
.custom-row-hover:hover {
  background-color: rgba(224, 248, 232, 1);
}
```

And the result is the same, again, first my color and then transitions to the default one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like the background color is applied to `td` element in antd table and also you need to increase the [specificity](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting) by using the `&&` operator. The updated code should look something like this for the `styledTable` component.

```
const StyledTable = styled((props) => <Table {...props} />)`
  && tbody > tr:hover > td {
    background: rgba(224, 248, 232, 1);
  }
`
```

To test the above, I forked the antd [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-and-operation-antd-4-17-0-alpha-3-forked-them9?file=/index.js:191-327) table demo and it seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you this solved it!, I did not need to increase specificity, but the selector did the trick! However even now when I am inspecting them, I dont see background set on the td at all, how can I inspect the `td` to see the styles being applied, when it depends on `tr:hover`?

Comment: If you inspect a particular td in the `Inspect` tab of chrome browser and select the `hover` checkbox in the `:hov` [tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/#pseudostates) on the parent `tr`, then you can see a background added to the td with a selector like this. `.ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-row:hover>td`

Comment: @Darkbound if this answer solved your question, mark it as the correct one

Comment: Helped me a lot, thank you!!

Comment: Not working through CSS file, not working as the styled component too. Things like text color are changing, except background color.

Answer (score 1):

in plain Css you must add td after tr:hover

```
.custom-row-hover:hover td {background: rgba(224, 248, 232, 1)!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done by changing the style of the row and cell of the table**

```
<Table
        dataSource={rowsWithButtonAction}
        columns={columns.map((col) => ({
          ...col,
          sorter: col.sorter || false, // Add sorter property to enable sorting
        }))}
        pagination={false}
        onRow={onRow}
        **rowClassName={rowClassName}**
        onChange={handlePageChange}
        style={{
          marginBottom: "10px",
        }}
        scroll={{ y: `calc(100vh - 300px)` }}
        loading={loading}
      />
```

First give **rowClassName** prop to the table component

And in that, you should assign your className to that row
I have assigned selected-row

```
 const rowClassName = (record) => {
return record.userId === "id you selected"
  ? `selected-row ${externalClass ? "custom-pointer" : ""}` //concatenating selected-row with custom-pointer
  : `${externalClass ? "custom-pointer" : ""}`;
```

};

I am changing the background color of selected-row

```
 .selected-row {
  background-color: #ecf2f4;
}
.selected-row:hover td {
  background-color: #ecf2f4 !important;
}
```

The **Antd tables** apply the hovered bg-color to **td** as well, so I have changed the styling of td along with the whole row.

I have done it for a specifically selected row, you can do it for each row as well

Hope this works for you! :)